# Does `dcos-cli` work with plain Mesos?

Tags: logging, command-line-interface, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I'm looking for a tool that will allow tailing of Mesos task `stderr` and `stdout` logs.

[`mesos-cli`](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-cli) seems to be such a tool, but it's been deprecated in favor of [`dcos-cli`](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-cli). The [documentation](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/logging/service-logs/) for `dcos-cli`, however, does not make clear whether and how it works with plain Mesos.

In summary: should I use `dcos-cli` or `mesos-cli` if I have Mesos but not DC/OS?

Comment: You can use [mesos-cli](https://github.com/apache/mesos/tree/master/src/cli) embeded in mesos

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `dcos-cli` to use a Mesos master instead of the DC/OS master for some operations, including task logging. Simply set the `core.mesos_master_url` configuration property, as documented on the [DC/OS CLI usage page](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/cli/):

```
$ dcos config set core.mesos_master_url 52.34.160.132:5050
```

You should then be able to use `dcos task log` to tail `stdout` and `stderr` for the tasks you're interested in.

Comment: When I try the command, I get `dcos cluster attach <cluster-name>`. But when i give the cluster name set for `mesos-master` with `--cluster=test` it says `Cluster [test] does not exist`. Note at mesos 5050 page top left I can see the same name.